# Accessing "private" members within an anonymous function outside scope

Tags: javascript

Basically what I am trying to do, is to provide access to "private" functions/variables for an anonymous function. I need some opinions about two ways I achieve this and possible better alternatives to these approaches. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qpvbxe2r/)

Observe the following snippet.

```
function Something()
{
    /*private*/ var _someVariable = 1;

    /*private*/ function _someFunction() {
        alert('_someFunction');
    }

    /*public*/this.SomeDelegate1 = function(codeblock) {
        var members = $.extend({ 
            _someVariable : _someVariable,
            _someFunction:_someFunction 
        }, this);           
        codeblock.apply(members);
    }

    /*public*/this.SomeDelegate2 = function(codeblock) {
        var caller = eval('(' + codeblock + ')');
        caller.apply(this);
    }           

}
```

In SomeDelegate1, I convert my private members to instance members and pass it as context to the
anonymous function like seen below.

```
var someInstance = new Something();
someInstance.SomeDelegate1(
    function() {
        this._someFunction();
        alert(this._someVariable);
    }
);
```

I like the fact that one can specify which members you would like to expose, but it can potentially get quite clunky e.g. when you need to update "private" variables for example.

I can obviously write all members as instance members, but I would rather prefer them to stay "private", only allowing access within scope of the callback function.

In SomeDelegate2, I use an eval (yes I am aware of all the evils and witchcraft associated with this).

```
var someInstance = new Something();
someInstance.SomeDelegate2(
    function() {
        _someFunction();
        alert(_someVariable);
    }
);
```

Since I am injecting code into the function, the "privately" scoped members are automatically available, so I don't need to do any copying of members etc and not a lot of work needs to be done otherwise.

Is there fundamental problems with this approach?

Do you have better alternatives/approaches to achieve this?

Comment: Seems like an XY problem to me. There's no private or public in JavaScript and I think approaching problems this way in JS is no good. You'll get more benefits, both in performance and API, if you use prototypes, and prefix properties that are not meant to be touched with an underscore as convention like you did.

Comment: Well aware of this, hence why I put private in quotes ;), they do however work in a similar way.

Comment: Not saying otherwise. But although they work similar, by not using prototypes you create those functions every time you create a new instance. And also, you can't use the functions without an instance.

Comment: True, just dont like leaving members exposed, but I guess its not like the code is "sealed" in any way...

Comment: @elclanrs So this would be your preference? http://jsfiddle.net/j7k8sj5w/

Comment: That would be an option, yes. I wouldn't even use `new` or constructor functions, after all those are basically old hacks now that we have `Object.create`.

Comment: I agree with @elclanrs. Make everything public and prefix variables which should be "private" with an underscore. That's the simplest and the most efficient solution. Stop worrying about which design pattern to use and start focusing on more important problems.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, I would make everything public and prefix "private" property names with an underscore. This is how I would restructure your code:

```js
function defclass(prototype) {
    var constructor = prototype.constructor;
    constructor.prototype = prototype;
    return constructor;
}

var Something = defclass({
    constructor: function () {
        this._someVariable = 1;
    },
    _someFunction: function () {
        alert("someFunction");
    },
    someDelegate1: function (f) {
        f.apply(this);
    },
    someDelegate2: function (f) {
        f.call(this, this._someVariable, this._someFunction);
    }
});

var someInstance = new Something;

someInstance.someDelegate1(function () {
    this._someFunction();
    alert(this._someVariable);
});

someInstance.someDelegate2(function (someVariable, someFunction) {
    someFunction();
    alert(someVariable);
});
```

However that's just my opinion. I don't really see the point of having private variables. Even if somebody messes with your private variables, it's their problem and not yours. It'll break their code and not yours.

Comment: I guess its just a concern brought forth from the other programming languages I use and since its something that can be avoided in JS (using scoping) as well.

The biggest thing with the approaches would merely be a guideline etc.

You don't see C# or PHP developers marking all members as public now do you?

Comment: I don't use C# or PHP but I do use C, and in C we don't have any "private" properties either. The entire concept of "private" and "public" properties is (in my humble opinion) superficial. It doesn't really matter whether your properties are private or public. Think about this: the Linux kernel is built using C (and a bit of assembly). If an popular OS kernel doesn't require private properties then why do you? What's the advantage of having private properties? If you really want to program defensively then why not make everything immutable and use functional programming languages? Problem gone

Comment: Encapsulation is one of the pillars of OOP, it can be argued that why do we really need OOP etc, but there are plenty of relevant material on the matter, bit of a different school of thought to yours I guess ;)

Comment: @cstruter The real problem in my opinion is mutable state. Most object-oriented programming languages are not very good at managing state. Hence they have a bunch of clumsy features like "private" and "protected" properties, which if you think about it are not really that important. There's a brilliant research paper published in 2006 by Ben Moseley and Peter Marks, and I highly recommend that you read it: http://shaffner.us/cs/papers/tarpit.pdf

Comment: I think this is a completely different discussion all together ;) One that requires a better setting.. But in context of javascript, it will probably boil down to best/common practices, javascript technically speaking not really being an OOP language.

Comment: @cstruter Encapsulation mandates that the state of an object and the operations that manipulate that state and grouped together into one logical unit. That's exactly what I have done in my answer above. Encapsulation has nothing to do with private properties and closures. However, as it turns out encapsulation is not that essential to OOP. It can easily be replaced by multi-methods. In multi-method based OOP the state and the methods are decoupled allowing for more flexibility. It's used widely in Common Lisp CLOS and newer languages like Magpie: http://magpie-lang.org/

Comment: @cstruter Technically speaking JavaScript is an OOP language. However unlike most OOP languages JavaScript doesn't make use of classes. Instead objects in JavaScript simply inherit from other objects (prototypes).

Comment: In a strict sense its not OOP ;) I think you need to read up a bit on encapsulation no offence.